# JS - Load JSON file content as a JS variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON file with content that looks like this:

```
//filename: b2021.json
[
//file content
]
```

And I have the following JS file:

```
//filename: code.js
arrayName = []

function write(){
     window.alert(arrayName); //This function is called on a HTML file
}
```

And my objective is to load the content from "b2021.json" into "arrayName" but I can't seem to find the right way to do it. Thanks in advance for those who help!

Comment: Where is it located? Are you using a tool like webpack or parcel?

Comment: Are we talking about node.js here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your environment.

On a browser, a couple of options:

- Use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) to load the file from the server, parse it, and store the result in `arrayName`. Note that this is an asynchronous process.

  For instance, in a modern browser with support for modules and [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await), you could do this in a module:

  ```
  const arrayName = await fetch("/path/to/your/file.json")
       .then(response => {
           if (!response.ok) {
               throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
           }
           return response.json();
       });
  ```

  In that code I intentioonally **don't** handle the promise rejection (which is normally an antipattern) on the basis that your module isn't of any use if the `fetch` fails. If you want your module to load even if the `fetch` fails, add a `catch`:

  ```
  const arrayName = await fetch("/path/to/your/file.json")
       .then(response => {
           if (!response.ok) {
               throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
           }
           return response.json();
       })
       .catch(error => {
           // ...report the error, then:
           return [/*...default array to use instead...*/];
       });
  ```
- If the file exists alongside your source code and you use a bundler of some kind (Webpack, Rollup, Parcel, etc.), many of them support *importing* JSON as though you were importing a module (either via ESM syntax — `import` — or CJS syntax — `require()`).

On Node.js:

Using CJS, you can `require()` the file; [details](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules).

Using ESM, you can `import` the file; [details](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_json_modules) — as of this writing, support for JSON modules in Node.js's ESM loader is experimental.

Answer (score 2):

On the client side, you can use the fetch api like so

```
fetch("b2021.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    arrayName = json;
  });
```

Edit: As evolutionxbox mentioned in the comment it is bad style to assign a global variable from a `then`-block. I would suggest to store the promise in a variable and call it from the `write()` function.

```
let fetchJson = fetch("b2021.json")
  .then(response => response.json());

function write(){
   // if promised was resolved before it is resolved instantly on subsequent calls
   fetchJson.then((arrayName) => window.alert(arrayName));
}
```

Comment: please do not modify global variables from a `then`

Comment: Good answer, particularly with the edit. Two other things to beware of: 1. It triggers the `fetch` API footgun (it doesn't check for HTTP success, see my post [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)), 2. It doesn't handle promise rejection.